# Is the following codes right? Can I make just one with this two codes?

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to make a script to start two applications 8:00pm and stop it 8:00am, removing a dir when it stops.
I can't test it right now and I'm new with AutoIt so if someone have any suggestions to my code or know another way to do it (I tried with Task Manager calling batch files but I had some issues). I'll be very happy with your help! 
My ideia is to make this script an exe and schedule with Task Manager to start on logon and when 8:00pm it start's the two applications (verifying the OS Arch). I need to make this applications stop 8:00am and I'm thinking in make a second script to do it, but if can be maked with just one script will be better.

It's for Windows machines, x64 or x86.

```
FIRST SCRIP: 
#include <Timers.au3>
#NoTrayIcon
#persistent

loop {                           
    If (A_Hour = 20) and (A_Min = 00) { ; is time 8:00pm?
        If @OSArch = "X64" Then 
            RunWait (C:\ProgramData\...\FirstApp.exe)
            Run (C:\ProgramData\...\SecondApp.exe)
        Elseif @OSArch = "X86" Then 
            RunWait (C:\ProgramData\...\FirstApp_x86.exe)
            Run (C:\ProgramData\...\SecondApp_x86.exe)
        EndIf
    }
    sleep, 1000 * 60  ; sleep for 60 seconds so only loop once per minute
}
return

SECOND SCRIPT:
#include <Timers.au3>
#NoTrayIcon
#persistent

loop {
    if (A_Hour = 08) and (A_Min = 00) { ; is time 8:00am?
        Run (@COMSPEC & "taskkill /F /IM FirstApp.exe", @SW_HIDE)
        Run (@COMSPEC & "taskkill /F /IM SecondApp.exe", @SW_HIDE)
        Run (@COMSPEC & "RMDIR C:\ProgramData\MyDir\ /S /Q", @SW_HIDE)
    }
    sleep, 1000 * 60  ; sleep for 60 seconds so only loop once per minute
}
return
```

Comment: I would highly suggest using the Task Scheduler to start these programs. It's going to be more reliable and easier on the CPU than constantly running a program.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your commands inside a function.

```
#include <Misc.au3> ; needed for _Singleton

_Singleton(@ScriptName, 0) ; allows one one instance of running script
HotKeySet("{ESC}", _close) ; [optional to exit script]

Do
    Sleep(20)

;waits for 8 AM 
If  @HOUR = "08" And @MIN = "00" And @SEC = "00" Then
    one()
EndIf

;waits for 8 PM 
If  @HOUR = "20" And @MIN = "00" And @SEC = "00"  Then
    two()
EndIf

Until  GUIGetMsg() = -3 ; $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE

Func one()

    ;Add the commmands you want executed at 8AM here

EndFunc   ;==>one

Func two()

    ;Add the commmands you want executed at 8PM here

EndFunc   ;==>two

Func _close()
    Exit
EndFunc
```